# What is the shell command to display contents of a file?

Tags: linux, shell

Like that of .txt or .html

Answer (score 100):

easiest are `cat`, `head`, `tail`, `tac` (for reverse output)

`less` and `more` let you scroll the text files (`less` being more powerful)

you can also use text editors like `nano`, `pico`, `vi`, `emacs`

Comment: "less is more", no not really, but still funny.

Comment: For novice users, it really isn't funny. Glib, and annoying.

Answer (score 17):

`cat` and `less` are good for this.

Answer (score 15):

To Display the contents of a file use this command:

cat

```
Code:
cat test.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use `cat`, although its really meant for concatenation of files. `more` or `less` are 2 other tools you can use. Other's include awk, eg
using awk

```
$ awk '1' file
```

using sed

```
$ sed -n '1,$p' file
```

using grep

```
$ grep "." file
```

using head/tail to display some parts of the file

```
$ head -1000 file
$ tail -1000 file
```

Tools aside, you can also use just the shell to display your file

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
done <"file"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `cat` , `head` or `tail`.

Answer (score 3):

For viewing HTML files you can also use `lynx`, `links`, `elinks` or `w3m` which are text-mode browsers. They can also be used to view .txt files.

Answer (score 2):

Or, `less` or `more`. See the `man` pages for more information. :)

Answer (score 2):

file  : Display the type of file
cat   : Display the content of the file and outputs it on stdout.

You can use vi, emacs command to edit the file in Unix environment. If you do not have expertise in using vi/emacs you might find it little difficult to edit the file.

If you have X11 enabled, You can use a number of Linux editors like gvim, kate, kwrite, kdevelop etc.

Kwrite is my personal favorite in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

`cat` Works fine with txt or html. (or less or more if you want tosee it page by page) or any text ediotr... (vi, emcas, gedit...).

Also know that if it's a binary file it's may contain control char that will do some displeasing things with your terminal (like changing charset). If that happen use `reset` to put it back in sane state.

You can also use `file` on file before displaying it's content, the system will guess it's type (based on content not filename name) and show it to you.