# Print the commnd run by shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to copy the files not present in one directory to the other directory by using awk

```
diff -r dir1 dir2 | grep dir1 | awk '{$1=$2=$3 =""; print "cp \"./dir1/" substr($0,4) "\" ./dir2/"}' | sh
```

This works fine except that I also want to print the file that is being copied. Something like `cp ./dir1/file1.txt ./dir2/` on `stdout`

How do I do this. I know it's simple but I can't figure it out. I tried `tee` and `echo` commands but in vain.

Comment: print on screen or print on some printer?

Comment: @AdamSilenko On screen or say stdout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the shell command to display contents of a file?](http://superuser.com/questions/112316/what-is-the-shell-command-to-display-contents-of-a-file)

Comment: Any reason not to use rsync?

Comment: @user657451 I didn't know about rsync. Not sure if it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `|sh -x`. From man page:

```
 -x xtrace
         Write each command (preceded by the value of the PS4 variable
         subjected to parameter expansion and arithmetic expansion) to
         standard error before it is executed.  Useful for debugging.
```

So shell will print to `stderr` all command executed. And you could use stderr redirection, like `|sh -x 2>commands_list.txt` to get list of command in separate file.

Comment: Great for seeing what a script is doing. But if you use a single command to copy a bunch of files, for example `cp *.txt newfolder/` this would only print the single command, not each file being copied.

Answer (score 1):

`cp` can tell you what it's doing too, it's option

```
-v, --verbose
          explain what is being done
```

prints to stdout what files are copied where, in the form:

```
‘file1’ -> ‘file2’
```

Comment: Yeah. This is so simple. Now i feel I have asked a stupid question.

Comment: Nah, good question. Most programs have a verbose or `-v` option to give more info on what they're doing, some (ex. `gpg`) will accept several v's for more "verbosity", always check the man page first (or sometimes info page, more info if it's different). I'll bet awk probably has a simple way to send a copy to stdout too but I'm not too current on it right now